# the value pointer points to is not updated

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Why here p->p1 is 1 rather than 0? I thought p is pointer to struct s2, and s2.p1=0, so p->p1 should be 0 too?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct S1 {
    int p1,p2;
};

struct S2 {
    int p1;
    struct S1 s1;
    int p2;
};


int main(void) {
    int s=0;
    struct S2 s2 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    struct S2 *p;
    p=(struct S2 *)malloc(sizeof(struct S2));
    *p = s2;
    s2.p1 = 0;
    s=p->p1 + s2.p1 + p->p2 + p->s1.p2;
    free(p);
    printf("%d", s);

    return 0;
}
```

I expected the output of 7, but the actual output is 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p` isn't actually pointing to `s2`!. You've copied `s2` into the address allocated at `p`. If you want `p` to point to `s2`, don't `malloc` it. Rather, simply say `struct S2 *p = &s2;`.

Answer (score 0):

`p` does not point to `s2`.  It points to allocated memory that contains a copy of what was in `s2` before it was modified.

Answer (score 0):

After this initialization

```
struct S2 s2 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

the data members of the object `s2` have the following values

```
s2.p1 = 1;
s2.s1.p1 = 2;
s2.s1.p2 = 3;
s2.p2 = 4;
```

Pay attention to that the pointer `p` points to a copy of the object `s2`. That is you have to objects one pointed to by the pointer `p` and other `s3` that became equal each other after the assignment

```
*p = s2;
```

bu they occupy different extents of memory.

So taking into account this statement

```
s2.p1 = 0;
```

the expression

```
p->p1 + s2.p1 + p->p2 + p->s1.p2
```

is equivalent tp

```
 1 + 0 + 4 + 3 == 8
```